# simple way to convert data into columns in ssms

Tags: sql, pivot, ssms, transpose

This is my script:

```
SELECT     
  LEFT(NARRKEY, 15) AS Business, 
  SUBSTRING(NARRKEY, 14, 10) AS [Sales Order], 
  SUBSTRING(NARRKEY, 24, 3) AS LINE, 
  NARRLINE$1 + ' ' + NARRLINE$2 + ' ' + NARRLINE$3 + ' ' + NARRLINE$4 + ' ' + NARRLINE$5 + ' ' + NARRLINE$6 + ' ' + NARRLINE$7 AS Text, 
  CASE 
    WHEN NARRPREFIX = 'J' THEN 'HEADER TEXT' 
    WHEN NARRPREFIX = 'I' THEN 'LINE TEXT' 
    ELSE NULL 
  END AS Expr2
 FROM   dbo.MAA040
 WHERE  (NARRLANG = 'E') 
 AND    (NARRSEQ = '000') 
 AND (NARRPREFIX = 'J' OR NARRPREFIX = 'I')
```

I want to be able to change the current column NARRPREFIX into two new columns which are HEADER TEXT and LINE TEXT, in the two new columns i would have the data from the text column dependent on if it were header text where it would populate the header column or line text where it would populate the line column

Comment: You haven't told us what your problem is or asked a question for us to answer.

Comment: yes i have - if you read at the bottom you will see what i want to be able to do with my script

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT     
  LEFT(NARRKEY, 15) AS Business, 
  SUBSTRING(NARRKEY, 14, 10) AS [Sales Order], 
  SUBSTRING(NARRKEY, 24, 3) AS LINE, 
  NARRLINE$1 + ' ' + NARRLINE$2 + ' ' + NARRLINE$3 + ' ' + NARRLINE$4 + ' ' + NARRLINE$5 + ' ' + NARRLINE$6 + ' ' + NARRLINE$7 AS Text, 
  CASE 
    WHEN NARRPREFIX = 'J' THEN 'HEADER TEXT' 
    WHEN NARRPREFIX = 'I' THEN 'LINE TEXT' 
    ELSE NULL 
  END AS Expr2,
CASE WHEN NARRPREFIX = 'J' THEN NARRLINE$1 + ' ' + NARRLINE$2 + ' ' + NARRLINE$3 + ' ' + NARRLINE$4 + ' ' + NARRLINE$5 + ' ' + NARRLINE$6 + ' ' + NARRLINE$7 END AS HeaderText,
CASE WHEN NARRPREFIX = 'I' THEN NARRLINE$1 + ' ' + NARRLINE$2 + ' ' + NARRLINE$3 + ' ' + NARRLINE$4 + ' ' + NARRLINE$5 + ' ' + NARRLINE$6 + ' ' + NARRLINE$7 END AS LineText

 FROM   dbo.MAA040
 WHERE  (NARRLANG = 'E') 
 AND    (NARRSEQ = '000') 
 AND (NARRPREFIX = 'J' OR NARRPREFIX = 'I')
```